# Javascript Check if value of a proeprty inside an array, that is a value of a property inside an object exists

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to check if the property exists already or not:

```
var objs = {
    '1': [ 'A-TheA', 'B-TheB' ],
    '2': [ 'A-TheA', 'B-TheB' ]
}
```

I want to check if  'A-TheA' exists in the object 1 or not in Property '1'.
Basically, I want to compare the first Character which is 'A', and it'll check the first letter of 'A-TheA', and if both matches, it will remove 'A-TheA' such that objs is now :

```
{
    '1': [ 'B-TheB' ],
    '2': [ 'A-TheA', 'B-TheB' ]
}
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: What about `B-TheB`?

Comment: `objs['1'] = objs['1'].filter(s => s[0] != 'A')`…?

Answer (score 0):

To check for this specific case:

```js
var objs = {
    '1': [ 'A-TheA', 'B-TheB' ],
    '2': [ 'A-TheA', 'B-TheB' ]
};
let index = objs['1'].indexOf('A-TheA');
if (index !== -1) {
    objs['1'].splice(index, 1);
}
console.log(objs)
```